# Bluetooth.ACTION_FOUND behaving weirdly

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am using broadcast receiver to scan for available devices. it was working at first, but then something happened and it started to find too many devices(there are only 3 bt device in room but it finds more than 10 sometimes) and only find their mac addresses(bluetoothDevice.name comes as null). I can't figure out why it's behaving like this

This is my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val receiver = MyBroadcast()
        val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter

        // request permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
                ), 1
            )
        }
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_b)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("TAG,", "clicked")
            bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()
            IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND).also {
                registerReceiver(receiver, it)
            }
        }


    }
}
```

This is the broadcast receiver:

```
class MyBroadcast:BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when(intent?.action) {
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                val device: BluetoothDevice =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)!!

                Log.i("here", device.toString())

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Broadcast"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there a lot of unnamed Bluetooth devices around which are nameless and you can't connect them either. So I had to check with `if(device.name!= null && device.address != null)` to get the names devices

Comment: Just curious, so there are actually more than 3 Bluetooth devices nearby?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm in an office so there are a lot of devices around me. but I don't know why Bluetooth shows a bunch of nameless devices. when I searched for their mac address  in a webpage to get the manufacturer, it couldn't find it.

Comment: I see. Thought you are in an isolated environment. Yes in such case, you will have to figure out some identifiers to filter out your targets.